# Rename class in accordance with SQL Server table in Entity Framework database-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have a database in SQL Server like this:

[image: SQL Tables]

Then I create a model as `.emdx` in my project by database (database-first approach):

[image: edmx]

I know class name in `.edmx` is according to SQL Server table but I need to class without prefix class name (remove `OnlineHelp_`).

I read many post but they are mostly about code-first and do not work well on my issue.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the EDMX Designer, you could select an entity, then modify the "Name" property, as shown in the following image (sorry for the italian screenshot)

[image: Screenshot]

The property will remain saved after a model refresh from database

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know I can rename entity name in property window but if I change table design (For example change column name), I should to delete entity and add it again because EF doesn't update entity properly. In this case name changed according to SQL table. Is there a way to solve this issue?